# How can I keep form inputs and labels together?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a web page with a form:

```html
<form>
  <label for="FirstName">First:</label>
  <input name="FirstName" type="text">
  <label for="MiddleName">Middle:</label>
  <input name="MiddleName" type="text">
  <label for="LastName">Last:</label>
  <input name="LastName" type="text">
</form>
```

If I size the browser window small enough, I get a line break between the label that says "Middle:" and the "MiddleName" input.  It would be better to put a break between labels and input fields that are not related, e.g. break between "FirstName" input and label for "MiddleName", and/or between input "MiddleName" and label for "LastName".  Obviously I can add `<br/>` tags, but is there a good way to keep the related items together, and still use only 1 line when the browser window is wide enough?

I realize this is a contrived example, but this is pattern I am having trouble with in several more complicated real world forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `input`s inside the `label`s, you don't even need the `for` attributes. Then style the labels with `white-space: nowrap` to prevent automatic line breaks.

```css
label { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<form>
<label>First: <input name="FirstName" type="text"></label>
<label>Middle: <input name="MiddleName" type="text"></label>
<label>Last: <input name="LastName" type="text"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Surround the related elements within an wrapper and then prevent line breaks **inside** the wrapper with CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <label for="FirstName">First:</label>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" />
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <label for="MiddleName">Middle:</label>
    <input name="MiddleName" type="text" />
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <label for="LastName">Last:</label>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" />
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can surround each set with a wrapper that is `display: inline-block;`

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* Only include this if 
         you don't want the text within the spans 
         to wrap when the window is small enough
  */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span class="wrap">
    <label for="FirstName">First:</label>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" />
  </span>
  <span class="wrap">
    <label for="MiddleName">Middle:</label>
    <input name="MiddleName" type="text" />
  </span>
  <span class="wrap">
    <label for="LastName">Last:</label>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" />
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: This works most of the time, but if the space gets small enough, the label and input will still wrap *within* the individual `<span>`s - better to use `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the OP wanted it to still break within the spans, "still use only 1 line when the browser window is wide enough".  Updated my answer to include both options.

Answer (score 1):

I use getuikit for form styling, they do it with something like this:

HTML

```
<label>My label</label>
<div class="controls"><input type=text/></div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px; //to center the label vertically
    width: 200px;
}

.controls {
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

It doesn't break semantics. Putting input inside label is little strange :)